# Getting UserAgent from code in a DLL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dll

The necessary references to System.Web and the Impports statement are already in the DLL

In code behind you can do this:

```
Dim MyString As String = Request.UserAgent
```

but transfer that code into a DLL and it's no good. I cannot seem to define ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT") either.

I have even tried this

```
Dim wr As System.Web.HttpRequest = New Web.HttpRequest(Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
Dim s As String = wr.UserAgent
```

but get an error Object Not Set... If I add a URL for the middle value as I don't require a Filename or a QueryString, no luck either.

```
Dim wr As System.Web.HttpRequest = New Web.HttpRequest(Nothing, "https://stackoverflow.com", Nothing)
Dim s As String = wr.UserAgent
```

How can I return the visitors UserAgent using code from a DLL an NOT Code Behind, please? I have checked for this answer on this site and couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When outside of code-behind you can do this:

```
Dim MyString As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent
```

[`HttpContext.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) also has properties for `Response`, `Server`, `Session`, and plenty of other useful values.